# HDMI no signal after installation of Ubuntu 21 on notebook [with broken matrix]

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 21 dual boot with win10.
I managed to create live USB which runs great on HDMI, but whatever I do, I always get no signal on HDMI output after installation reboot.
I did also tried installing Ubuntu 20, for which installator works ultra slow (3-4 sec for reaction after any click) but after reboot I got signal as long as I didn't update Ubuntu and install Nvidia drivers (tried with different versions for my 1050 ti) - after that no signal but was able to blind login to system and even blind use console. My HDMI works for sure ( as installation process is visible ) and I tried on different external displays. Have only one output ( no dp or pc ). Tried also disk boot repair from yannubuntu but with no effect. My laptop is Acer an515-51. Another thing is also that I cannot force UEFI settings to display through HDMI even with cable disconnected from broken matrix.
Searched through a lot of posts in the internet but none of them match my situation(started trying more then one week ago, and also with other distros like fedora)
Is that even possible to fix it without my laptop built in display ?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 21, nor a Ubuntu 20.  There is a Ubuntu Core 20, but it's a different product to the more common Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system; as Ubuntu has used *year* for specialist *snap* only releases since 2016, with the *year.month* format used for standard *deb* based systems.  The *year* format systems are server only and not intended for desktop use.

Comment: The details and terms in this question are not clear.  It's difficult to understand what you are trying to say.  Can you define the terms "blind login" and "blind use console"?  Also explain what is meant by "force UEFI settings to display through HDMI".  What does "cable disconnected from broken matrix" mean?  When you say "is it even possible to fix it without my laptop built in display", are you telling us that your hardware is broken and that your display doesn't even work?  How can you be sure of anything you're doing in that case?

Comment: Quite easy, as long as You can login to your Ubuntu system, press Ctrl alt t , it will run the terminal,then simply press backspace which will trigger the sound that informs you that there is no text input so You cannot "backspace" anything, same with UEFI settings, using pictures of my version of UEFI settings screen I was able to set boot order, set supervisor password, disable secure boot, save and exit, now I am wondering if I can also try to blind repair or maby repair using live usb what I described

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to disable secure boot properly, apt upgrade once again for Nvidia drivers needed upgrade again and change primary selected GPU to Nvidia ( after Nvidia drivers installation and reboot it changed GPU to integrated Intel...)
Thank You all